# Scenebuilder in Intellij Pathway Setup

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, path, scenebuilder

IT student here.

Scenebuilder was working fine, until I tried to open a different .fxml from the one I was working on. Then Scenebuilder stopped working. Tried going back and opening the file I was working on fine previously, and that suddenly wouldn't open.

Looked on here and reddit for other solutions. People recommended going through IntelliJ "File> Settings> Languages & Frameworks> JavaFX" and fixing the Path to Scenebuilder. When I would do what I would think would fix it, it would spit a mirror image with different slashes. I took a picture of one of the results I got. I've tried flipping the slashes for the path, I've tried using the path that's the same as the file I'm trying to access, I've tried finding the scenebuilder file, but all I have can find is the installer, which makes no sense because I was just editing a different .fxml a few minutes ago.

Can anybody help me? I would like to be able to do my homework, but I'd also love to understand what's going on. I feel like a hot mess and a big dummy at the same time right now lol.

[Example from my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpDOK.png)

TIA!

Comment: You can download and run [SceneBuilder separately](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) rather than running it from the idea IDE.

Comment: It looks like the path you set for SceneBuilder is pointing to your IntelliJ project, which doesn't make sense. I'm on a Mac, so it may be different, but there is a "Browse" button on the text field for "Path to SceneBuilder". Just press that button and find the SceneBuilder executable. It should be under your "Program Files" folder somewhere. It will probably use forward slashes to represent path separators, as back slashes are escape characters in Java (and every other IT technology, except for the idiotic Windows filesystem).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks -- I swapped over to running Scenebuilder through the app, and I was able to set up the pathway too. Running it through the IDE was super buggy lol